# How to adjust parabolic trajectory to hit the same point with the same launch angle, but faster speed?

Tags: libgdx, movement, box2d

I'm launching a ballistic projectile [similar to this sample](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/projected-trajectory).

The projectile moves from the launch point to the target point, but it's too slow. When I try to increase the speed without changing the angle, it misses the target point.

Here is the code I use to set the projectile's velocity given the launch speed and angle:

```
float speed = 45;
float angle = (float) (90 * Math.PI / 180f);
cpBody.body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(
          speed * (float) Math.cos(angle), 
          speed * (float) Math.sin(angle)
));
cpBody.body.setAwake(true);
cpBody.body.setGravityScale(1);
cpBody.body.setAngularVelocity(0);
```

And I display the body positions like so:

```
  for (Entity entity : bodiesQueue) {
      CPTransform tfm = mCPTransform.get(entity);
      CPBody cpBody = mCPBody.get(entity);
      Vector2 positionBody = cpBody.body.getPosition();
      tfm.position.x = positionBody.x;
      tfm.position.y = positionBody.y;
      tfm.rotation = cpBody.body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees;
  }
```

I want to travel with the same angle and faster velocity. The destination x,y does not change. How can I speed up the projectile without missing?

Comment: I've edited your question so it describes the actual problem and goal, rather than a red herring about the angle being wrong. Please be careful to ask for what you actually need - it saves a lot of time when we don't need to clarify the issue in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given gravity value and target point, there's a one-to-one relationship between launch speed and angle that will hit that point. Any other speed with the same angle will either fall short (if it's too slow) or overshoot (if it's too fast). So you cannot change the speed alone.

The only way to get a parabola with the same launch angle to hit the same target point at a faster speed is to increase gravity.

We can work out the needed gravity for a given speed like so:

First, if we're travelling at speed \$s\$, at a given angle \$\theta\$, our velocity components are \$v_x = s \cos \theta\$ and \$v_y = s \sin \theta\$.

At that speed, we'll reach the target's horizontal position at time \$t^*\$, using \$L\$ for the launch position and \$T\$ for the target position:

$$\begin{align}
L_x + t^* v_x &= T_x\\
t^* v_x &= T_x - L_x\\
t^* &= \frac {T_x - L_x} {v_x}
\end{align}$$

At that time, our vertical velocity, bent by gravity, will have taken us to a height of:

$$\begin{align}
h(t) = L_y + t v_y + t^2 \frac {a_g} 2\\
h(t^*) = L_y + t^* v_y + {t^*}^2 \frac {a_g} 2 &= T_y\\
{t^*}^2 \frac {a_g} 2 &= T_y - L_y - t^* v_y\\
a_g &= \frac 2 {{t^*}^2}\left(T_y - L_y - t^* v_y \right)\\
\end{align}$$

That gives you the rate of acceleration due to gravity needed to bend the trajectory down to hit the target y at the same time we hit the target x.